# I cannot get my ProcessingJS Sketch to load External resources

Tags: javascript, resources, processing, external

https://www.khanacademy.org/cs/test2/5075302188843008
There is the link to my program on Khan Academy, I've gotten it to work with JSON, but it seems to not be too happy when I try to modify it. I've saved it modified for an example. I really want to know how to get this to work with all file types, so if you could refer me to a page, or just tell me how, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

**I didn't tried with processing.js but in Javascript you would do something like this :**

Assuming you've got a Json file like this :

```
{
    "test": {
        "votes": [
            "1",
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4",
            "5"
        ]
    }
}
```

in your html page add in a `<script>` tag :

```
function getVotes(url) {
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');
    ajax.open('get', url, true); 
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){    
        if(ajax.readyState==4){
            parseJSON(ajax.responseText);
            }
    };
        ajax.send(null);
}



function parseJSON(json){

var chatVotes = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(chatVotes.test.votes);
// returns " ["1", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"] "
}

getVotes("yourJsonFile.json");
```

**You should watch [this link](http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html#accessingjsobjectsfrompjs) to learn how to access javascript data within your processing.js program.**

You might also want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6444811/3702797) from a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/843792/3702797).

*Ps: AFAIK JSON.parse() can only parse valid json data. The url you're accessing in your code is html data.*

Comment: Is there any way where I could just receive raw text documents? I've been trying but there has been no avail.